# Upgrade to 3.6 Error: One of Craft CMS’s migrations failed. Undefined class constant 'Trial'

Tags: plugin-freeform, upgrades

I am trying to update to Craft 3.6 but getting the following error:

Is it related to a plugin being on Trial? I have the plugin Freeform on Trial during development.

```
Error: Undefined class constant 'Trial'

Migration: craft\migrations\m201124_003555_plugin_trials

Output:

Exception: Undefined class constant 'Trial' (C:\Websites\grants\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\migrations\m201124_003555_plugin_trials.php:22)
#0 C:\Websites\grants\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\db\Migration.php(52): craft\migrations\m201124_003555_plugin_trials->safeUp()
#1 C:\Websites\grants\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\db\MigrationManager.php(232): craft\db\Migration->up(true)
#2 C:\Websites\grants\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\db\MigrationManager.php(148): craft\db\MigrationManager->migrateUp(Object(craft\migrations\m201124_003555_plugin_trials))
#3 C:\Websites\grants\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\services\Updates.php(250): craft\db\MigrationManager->up()
#4 C:\Websites\grants\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\controllers\BaseUpdaterController.php(509): craft\services\Updates->runMigrations(Array)
#5 C:\Websites\grants\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\controllers\UpdaterController.php(203): craft\controllers\BaseUpdaterController->runMigrations(Array, 'restore-db')
#6 [internal function]: craft\controllers\UpdaterController->actionMigrate()
#7 C:\Websites\grants\craft\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 C:\Websites\grants\craft\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(181): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#9 C:\Websites\grants\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Controller.php(190): yii\base\Controller->runAction('migrate', Array)
#10 C:\Websites\grants\craft\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(534): craft\web\Controller->runAction('migrate', Array)
#11 C:\Websites\grants\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Application.php(274): yii\base\Module->runAction('updater/migrate', Array)
#12 C:\Websites\grants\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Application.php(665): craft\web\Application->runAction('updater/migrate')
#13 C:\Websites\grants\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Application.php(212): craft\web\Application->_processUpdateLogic(Object(craft\web\Request))
#14 C:\Websites\grants\craft\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(392): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#15 C:\Websites\grants\craft\web\index.php(21): yii\base\Application->run()
#16 {main}
```

Comment: How are you doing the upgrade? From the control panel or from the command line? It looks like maybe some required files are missing.

Comment: I have tried both the control panel and the command line.
When I do it via the command line it completes ok - then when I go to the Control panel it wants to Finished updates to the database which is when it crashes.